# Expected value of drawing a green ball followed by yellow ball

Tags: probability, solution-verification

An urn has $k$ green balls and $j$ yellow balls. We draw them one by one, without replacement, until the urn is empty. What's the expected number of times where we draw a green ball followed by a yellow ball?

Here's how I did it. We have $k + j$ total balls, so there are $k + j - 1$ "pairs" i.e., (draw #1, draw #2) is a pair, (draw #2, draw #3) is another pair, etc.. For any pair $(i, i+1)$, I define a random variable that takes on value $1$ if the first draw in the pair was green and the second draw was yellow, 0 otherwise. So the Expected Value of this random variable is

$$\frac{kj}{(k + j)(k + j - 1)}$$

And the final answer is just the fraction above multiplied by $k + j - 1$ - the total number of pairs. Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Yes.  Using Indicator Random Variables and Linearity of Expectation is a correct approach.  Also the answer is correct too.